# VS 2012 MVC4 facebook template: Given URL is not permitted by the application configuratio

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to make MVC4 facebook application using VS 2012 Facebook template. When I run the application keep on getting "Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

Got following configuration in the web.config

> ```
> <add key="Facebook:AppId" value="7XXXXXXX64" />
> <add key="Facebook:AppSecret" value="e7066XXXXXXXX344" />
> <add key="Facebook:AppNamespace" value="mynotepadapp" />
> <add key="Facebook:AuthorizationRedirectPath" value="~/Home/Permissions" />
> <add key="Facebook:VerifyToken:User" value="" />
> ```

I have added www.example.com in my host file. What I am missing here? Also I tried site URL and Canvas URL with out "www". Didnt work either.

[image: Facebook app configuration]

Comment: Did you use example.com is the actual Facebook interface? I think that domain is blacklisted for callback URLs since it's owned by IANA.

Comment: yeah that is what I have in AppDomains and SiteURL and CanvasURL. I tried localhost first. Id didnt work either. Should I try different domain name?

Comment: well I tried a different domain name. No luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to make mvc4 template to work with localhost

- You dont change hosts file, leave that one as it is
- on Facebook app configuration page under settings > Basic
- App Domains is Empty
- Canvas url/Canvas Secure url: https: //  localhost : port number/  (sorry stackoverflow wont let me write the url properly)
- SiteUrl same as canvas url
- Your Sandbox mode should be enabled if using localhost

Make sure your Canvas and canvas secure are both https and ends with /

In Web.config, write your appkey, appsecret and appnamespace

Note: there is no place where you need to enter example.com

Hope it helps